# creative sdk of Adobe crashed in iOS project

Tags: ios, adobe, adobecreativesdk

1.I have followed the document  actually

2.the crash reason is +[AVYContentPack installIndexUpdateContext]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x100407cf0，but I cannot find the class named AVYContentPack in creative sdk

3.I have no idea，could you please help me solve this problem ？

Comment: Have the same exact issue, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution was adding the missing "**-ObjC**" flag in "Other Linker Flags"

*Add linker flags:*

Select Build Settings -> Linking -> Other Linker Flags. (If you do not see this setting, see if Basic is selected in Xcode and click All instead.)
Double-click the empty area to the right. An empty window pops up for you to add or delete values.
Click the + (plus sign) button, and add a new value "-ObjC"